# Getting just new mail from Exchange, ignore Meeting Requests

Tags: java, imap, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

When I getting new messages with javamail from exchange IMAP, it return all items include MeetingRequest items. How to ignore them, and get just email messages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out how meeting requests differ from other messages.  Do they have a distinctive subject?  Do they come from a special user?  If so, you can use the Folder.search() method to find only messages that match that criteria.

Comment: well i am using javamail to connect to users mailbox. Folder.search is method of EWS. 
UPD. Sorry. i have just lookup to javamail API and found what you mean. Will try your suggest